# Python iterating and appending over midlevel in list of list of lists

Tags: python, list

dumb question: I have a list of lists of lists

```
newlist=[]

listoflist=[ 
[['fal', 'AI-state', 'auto-vai-12', 'PV/e', 'PV/ohci', 'V', 'AI', 'Cnj', 'Prs', '3Sg', '@PRED-AI'], ['bkjr', 'NDA-Relations.actor', 'N.actor', 'A.actor', 'D.actor', 'Px1Sg.actor', 'Sg.actor', '@ACTOR>.actor']], 
[['sven', 'NI-object', 'auto-vii-2', 'PV/kaa', 'V', 'II', 'Cnj', 'Prs', '3Sg', 'Err/Orth', '@PRED-II']], 
[['trk', 'AI-do', 'auto-vai-9', 'PV/kaa', 'V', 'II', 'Cnj', 'Prs', '3Sg', '@PRED-II']], 
[['sdr', 'TI-do', 'auto-vti-4', 'PV/e', 'V', 'TI', 'Cnj', 'Prt', '3Sg', '@PRED-TI'], ['fgdfg.actor', 'NDA-Relations.actor', 'auto-nda-1.actor', 'N.actor', 'A.actor', 'D.actor', 'Px1Sg.actor', 'Sg.actor', '@<ACTOR.actor']]
]
```

I want to iterate through `listoflists`, and for every `midlist` in it append them to `newlist`, UNLESS any of the `terminallist`s in the `midlist` does **not** contain the string 'auto'.

Desired result would be a `newlist` that looks like

```
[ 
[['sven', 'NI-object', 'auto-vii-2', 'PV/kaa', 'V', 'II', 'Cnj', 'Prs', '3Sg', 'Err/Orth', '@PRED-II']], 
[['trk', 'AI-do', 'auto-vai-9', 'PV/kaa', 'V', 'II', 'Cnj', 'Prs', '3Sg', '@PRED-II']], 
[['sdr', 'TI-do', 'auto-vti-4', 'PV/e', 'V', 'TI', 'Cnj', 'Prt', '3Sg', '@PRED-TI'], ['fgdfg.actor', 'NDA-Relations.actor', 'auto-nda-1.actor', 'N.actor', 'A.actor', 'D.actor', 'Px1Sg.actor', 'Sg.actor', '@<ACTOR.actor']]
]
```

I originally tried something like

```
otherlist=[]
for midlist in listoflists:
    for terminallist in midlist:
        if any("auto" in tag for tag in terminallist):
            newlist.append(midlist)
        else:
            otherlist.append(midlist)
```

But of course this added a `midlist` twice due to the iteration for every `terminallist`s

Comment: What is `clause`?

Comment: Maybe you should just not write a loop `for terminallist in midlist`?

Comment: Good old `break` should also help...

Comment: Please provide a [mre], meaning reduce the input data for the sake of example, provide the current output, and fix the bad names, i.e. `clause` is not defined and typo `lisoflist` ->  `listoflists`.

Comment: @wjandrea, sorry about that. It should be good now.

Comment: @BOBjwjwj3j3j `listoflists` is still undefined. There's still a typo: `listoflist`

Comment: @BOBjwjwj3j3j and please try to reduce the input data for the sake of example.

Comment: @EdoAkse I can't believe I forgot to break...